# Force induced in a coil by a moving magnet

Tags: electromagnetism

So a magnet moves towards one end of a coil. A pole is induced in this end of the coil that opposes the pole of the magnet moving towards it (e.g. south pole induced to oppose the north pole of the moving magnet).
Now my question is, which direction would the coil move (if it were to)?
North-South should result in attraction, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, if the north pole of the magnet is brought closer to the coil, anticlockwise current will develop in the coil as seen from the magnet side. This corresponds to North pole on the coil and not South pole. So essentially there will be repulsion.

Comment: So the coil will move away, then?

Comment: yes it will move away. Did you get why it is North pole?

Comment: Yeah. Lenz's Law. Thanks a lot. However, I was wondering about the situation of the poles as the magnet moves away from the opposite end and south is facing the end of the coil?

Comment: In that case as magnet moves away lesser field lines will pass through coil. By Lenz law again anticlockwise current will develop. So attractive force